# SVG Stroke as Solid then Gradient

Tags: svg, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to draw an SVG `Path` element like the image attached in one go: where the stroke would be solid until a certain percentage then become a gradient until the end.

I cannot use multiple `Path` elements unfortunately, only a single one, since I'm using the `react-charts` [Line](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Line) element which translates to a single SVG `Path` and only allows stroke modifications.

Basically I need a `Path` with a solid stroke that stops at a given point and continues as a dashed stroke or as a gradient. I tried the following (assuming I want to start the non-solid stroke at 60%):

```
    <linearGradient id="gradient1" y1="0%" y2="0%" x1="0%" x2="200%">
      <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="60%"  stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="70%"  stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="70%"  stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="80%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="80%"  stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="black" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
```

But it's not providing a very smooth effect. Should I just increase `stop` steps? Are there any better ideas?

[image]

Comment: use 2 overlapped paths: the bottom one with the gradient; the other one: a black stroke dasharray to the percentage you need. If you need more help please update your question and add a working example

Comment: Sorry about that; done.

Comment: "I'm unable to provide a linear-gradient to the stop color." - what does that mean? If you need to use the library unmodified, you can't do what you need to do since the library doesn't have that functionality. Since you have to modify the library anyway, you can do anything you want, including drawing the line twice.